# SQL subquery column not showing

Tags: mysql, sql

Currently I am attempting to query particular columns from two separate tables. To do this, I am electing to use a `SELECT` statement within the `FROM` clause.

Here is the following query I am attempting:

```
SELECT Employees.Last_Name, Employees.First_Name, Employees.PositionID FROM 
Employees,
   (SELECT Positions.PositionID, SUM(Positions.Position_Salary) AS Salary FROM 
   Positions GROUP BY PositionID) AS Subquery
   WHERE Employees.PositionID = Subquery.PositionID
```

As we can see, I am trying to group each record according to its respective `PositionID` with a summation column for `Salary`. Unfortunately, the `Salary` column doesn't appear.

Observe:

[image]

In subsequent tests, I removed the Employee.First_Name, Employee.Last_Name but the summed column of Salary still did not appear.

Any idea what is going on here?

Comment: Try Selecting Subquery.SALARY column in your first SELECT

Comment: yes but Salary is located in the Positions table, not in the Employees table (which is what the first select statement is pulling from)

Comment: What happened when you try to SELECT Subquery.Salary in first SELECT?

Comment: See my reply to The Impaler below. He suggested that as well.

Comment: Can't you join tables instead of using nested SELECT?

Comment: Yeah, but surely its possible to use subqueries to achieve the same goal

Comment: @Matthew Is an employee assigned more than 1 positions and are there more than 1 salaries for the same position?

Comment: @forpas There is only one salary per position. Each employee is assigned a position and be default assigned  a salary. So, I am trying to group employees of the same type of position together and get the total amount of money paid to each department

Comment: Then how do you expect to  get names in the results? You will get positions and total salaries per position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you want for each employee the total salaries of its position:

```
SELECT 
  Employees.Last_Name, 
  Employees.First_Name, 
  Employees.PositionID,
  (SELECT SUM(Positions.Position_Salary) 
   FROM Positions 
   WHERE Employees.PositionID = Positions.PositionID) AS TotalSalary
FROM Employees
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the `Salary` column to the `SELECT` clause:

```
SELECT Employees.Last_Name, Employees.First_Name, Employees.PositionID,
Subquery.Salary -- added it here
FROM Employees,
(SELECT Positions.PositionID, SUM(Positions.Position_Salary) AS Salary FROM 
 Positions GROUP BY PositionID) AS Subquery
WHERE Employees.PositionID = Subquery.PositionID
```

Comment: That shows the Salary per individual, but unfortunately it does not group salaries according to the PositionID (indicated by the `GROUP BY` clause)

Comment: How come? In your query you defined `Salary` as `SUM(Positions.Position_Salary)`. It is the aggregation of `Position_Salary`.

Comment: I'm not sure why its not working. It displays Salary as I said, but it does not aggregate according to Position_Salary*